# Secured endpoints and redoploy issue

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I played around with endpoints and noticed that after the deployment of a new appengine version and making that one the default all existing logged in clients started to get unauthorized exceptions.

What am I missing? Is this the way it is supposed to work?

Comment: In my knowledge about oauth2 this is not how it should behave. An access_token does not lose its validity when you make minor code changes. Please provide more information about the nature of the newly deployed changes and how you access the endpoints from your clients. Also, is this behavior reproducable in a minimalistic version of your app and can you provide such an app to analyze this further?

Comment: Ok I will investigate this further. I'll be back!